# Concerning extracting the size info of the image

Tags: image, dimension, dm-script

I am trying to extract the dimension size info of the image with GetSize() and Get3DSize() as follows:

```
try { 2DData.Get3DSize (sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ); }
catch { 2DData.GetSize (sizeX, sizeY); Break; } 
OKDialog ("Size in Z direction ="+ sizeZ)
```

For 2D data, Get3DSize() apparently does not work and the stuff within catch() will be executed to catch this error. Strange is that the size in the Z direction can still be extracted and it is **1**. What happens here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GMS will internally use dimension size 1 for "non-existing" dimensions.

`GetSize()` and `Get3DSize()` are only old convenience "shorthand" commands. I would recommend using:

- `ImageGetDimensionSize()` to access a specific dimensions.
- `ImageGetNumDimensions()` to query the number of existing dimensions.
- `ImageGetDimensionSizes()` to read multiple dimensions at once, f.e. to compute the number of values in an image. That's where "1" comes in handy.

```c
    image test := realImage("",4,100)
//    image test := realImage("",4,10,20)
//    image test := realImage("",4,10,20,30)
    number x,y,z
    test.ImageGetDimensionSizes(x,y)
    result("\n x="+x)
    result("\n y="+y)
    test.ImageGetDimensionSizes(x,y,z)
    result("\n x="+x)
    result("\n y="+y)
    result("\n z="+z)
    result("\n # values:"+(x*y*z))
```

Comment: Thanks for this info and these commands seem to be more general and applicable, which avoid the use of Try() and Catch().